# Is it possible to set a cookie on an iframe?

Tags: azure, authentication, adal

In our web application's UI, we load a video in an iframe. The video is on office 365/SharePoint server.

If the user is not logged into the organization's portal managed by Azure ADAL, a login screen is loaded in the iframe. If the user is already logged in the video plays normally.

So far fine. But our management do not want the iframe redirected to login page and instead set a cookie on the iframe and load the video.

We said that it is not possible to set a cookie on an iframe and send a request and also we asked how can we get Microsoft cookies into our application? The architect says there is a rest endpoint which will give the details of the cookie. But still we do not have idea how to set it.

Is it really possible to set cookies and send to Microsoft portal to avoid authentication? I believe it is not possible but the architects and management insists we try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's not possible to set a cookie "per frame", but I guess you can login the user ("somehow", see below) and then reload the frame (or check authentication before even trying to load the frame).

Idea to login silently:

1. Create an account on your SharePoint which is only allowed to watch the selected videos (aka a "Public-User")
2. Automatically login all not already authenticated users with this account

   1. Maybe with a rest call to the SharePoint server, check whether the user is logged in
   2. If not logged in, maybe in a (hidden) frame send the login data for the Public-User to the SharePoint
   3. All future requests should have the cookie set.
3. Show them the video

But for the idea to manually set the cookie: Due to security issues, browsers won't let you (= your web application) to read or write cookies for another domain (= the SharePoint server).

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.
We accomplished something like this through the use of a proxy server.

In short, the proxy (hosted in elastic beanstalk) would notice a request coming in, check it's cookies for one that we set to determine the user is logged in, and if it found that cookie on the request it would call some authorization endpoints with it to be able to append a new cookie onto the response (set-cookie header) which we would then use to determine how to proceed. The proxy was written with node.js/express.

As long as you end up having sameSite: 'None' on the cookie options when you are setting the cookie it should work, even though the site hosting the iframe is on another domain.

I'm not sure if this relates into your bigger picture, but maybe gives some inspiration to others with similar issues.